# How to change a package's keyboard shortcut chosen during upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have recently upgraded my distro from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. To do so, I used [this guide](https://www.linuxtechi.com/upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-to-ubuntu-22-04/).
Everything went well, except for one thing, which is my own fault.

I had to configure a package during the upgrading, where I had to choose a keyboard shortcut to "change the keyboard layout to latin characters" or something like that.

Well I set it to the `Alt Gr` key (the one to the right of the space key).

The problem is, I always have to press that key when I am typing special characters (such as `{`, `[`, `]`, or `}`). And so it always switches my keyboard layout from [the Canadian multilingual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSA_keyboard#/media/File:KB_Canadian_Multilingual_Standard.svg) to [the French AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY#/media/File:KB_France.svg), before I get to type a special character.

I have checked in my shortcuts (those in `Parameters > Keyboards > Shortcuts`), the keyboard shortcut to change the keyboard layout is set to `Super + space`.

I can cycle through all my keyboards with `Super + space`, but whenever I press `Alt Gr`, I go back to the French AZERTY layout.

So I guess that, during the upgrade, I set a package that deals with this shortcut, but I can't remember which one. Again, I only remember that the shortcut is used to "revert to a latin layout" or something like that.

I am sorry that I can't describe my problem more properly.

Does anyone know the package that has this shortcut set, and how I can remove it?

Or is there a way to look for the packages that have keyboard shortcuts set?

Or, maybe, a workaround?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install "Gnome Tweaks". On the "Keyboard & Mouse" tab, click the button "Additional Layout Options" and change the options under "Switching to another layout".

If that option was set as system default, you could remove it by editing the line `XKBOPTIONS=` in the file `/etc/default/keyboard` (as root, because this is a system file). The option to use <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is called `grp:toggle`. To remove all options, just make sure the line reads `XKBOPTIONS=""`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked with the Gnome Tweaks!